# Regular expressions in python : don't split when a specific substring is found

Tags: python, regex

I found a bug in a regex in one of python-scripts and I need help to solve it.
The problem is that the script splits a string with `re.split('(V[A-Z])', string)` but I don't want a split if the specific substring SVD is found.

example:
"ACD VU LSF VMSUGH VIJ SVD HJV DVO" -> "ACD ", "U LSF ","MSUGH ", "IJ SVD HJV D", "O"

Is there someone out there that can solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use lookbehind assertion in regex. 
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

```
>>>x = 'ACD VU LSF VMSUGH VIJ SVD HJV DVO'
>>>result = re.split('V[A-Z](?<!SVD)', x)
['ACD ', ' LSF ', 'SUGH ', 'J SVD HJV D', '']
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm...

```
if 'SVD' not in string:
    result = re.split('(V[A-Z])', string)
else:
    result = string
```